# Retrieve data from 2 tables with matching rows in 2 different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data like this:

`TableA`:

```
itm_id  itm_desc    accountNumber   branchName
--------------------------------------------------
1       iphone-13   12345          Mylapore
2       dellv4      23456          Triplicane
3       Lenova2     34567          Srirangam
```

`TableB`:

```
itm_id  itm_new_desc    newaccountnumber    qty 
----------------------------------------------------
1       iphone-14       A12345          10
2       dellv5          B23456          12
3       Lenova5         C34567          17
```

Is there a way to retrieve data from both the tables in 2 different rows in a single SQL?

For example my output should be..

```
itm_id  itm_desc    accountNumber branchName    itm_new_desc    newaccountnumber    qty
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       iphone-13   12345          Mylapore
1                                               iphone-14       A12345          10
2       dellv4      23456          Triplicane
2                                               dellv5          B23456          12
3       Lenova2     34567          Srirangam
3                                               Lenova5         C34567          17
```

This is for SQL Server.

Comment: use `UNION ALL`

Comment: Why do you need to combine the data in such way? Maybe you need to use LEFT JOIN, to see 1 row for each itm_id and see both old and new values in one row?

Comment: Love to see what you tried and got stuck with.

Answer (score 1):

Union them together. Where a field exists in one table but not the other, use NULL. You might need to cast the nulls in the top query to the datatype from the bottom query, I can't remember if it does it for you or not.

```
    select itm_id, itm_desc, accountNumber, branchName, null 'itm_new_desc', null 'newaccountnumber', null 'qty'
    from TableA

    union all

    select itm_id, null, null, null, itm_new_desc, newaccountnumber, qty
    from TableB
    order by itm_id
```

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks. I always make the mistake of thinking the order by will apply to one of the queries and not the final result. Edited.

Comment: Note that tables have columns, not fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query, but I'm not sure, why you need to combine data in such way.

```
select
  itm_id,
  itm_desc,
  accountNumber,
  branchName,
  null as itm_new_desc,
  null as newaccountnumber,
  null as qty
from TableA
union all
select
  itm_id,
  null as itm_desc,
  null as accountNumber,
  null as branchName,
  itm_new_desc,
  newaccountnumber,
  qty 
from TableB
```

Comment: You do know that html snippets don't work with SQL right?